# c++ double & usage

Tags: c++, reference

Sometimes I see function declare like this:

```
void foo(vector<some type>&& inputs);
```

What is the major reason to use && instead of &?

Comment: Probably the two most common major reasons are to allow move semantics and perfect forwarding.

Comment: @Ben, yes, it does indeed look like a duplicate. I think my answer's better than that thread's answer though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new thing in C++11 called rvalue references.

You can read a great introduction to them here: http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

Essentially, it says it will be a reference to an object which can be destroyed without causing problems, and is used to optimise certain operations such as copy constructors (which can be changed for a swap if the other object can be destroyed).